# Names of log archives generated using Log4j2

Tags: log4j2

Here i am trying to implement Log4j2 archival strategy using DefaultRollOverStrategy. Basically i want to have number of archive files being generated once size of actual file crosses 10Mb.
With current programmatic configuration i am able to do so, but problem here is archived file name is not reflecting accurate time part.

For example, over the period log archives are generated but time part(highlighted) is not changing

Sample-**2019-12-02_17-09-37**-1.log

Sample-**2019-12-02_17-09-37**-2.log

Sample-**2019-12-02_17-09-37**-3.log

Sample-**2019-12-02_17-09-37**-4.log

I am sharing XML representation of configuration generated grammatically, rather than XML based config.

````
<Configuration name="RollingBuilder" status="DEBUG">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="XYZRollingFileAppender" fileName="logs/Sample.log" filePattern="logs/Sample-${date:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}-%i.log" createOnDemand="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="XYZRollingFileAppender"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="com.sample.test" level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="XYZRollingFileAppender"/>
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>```
````